# Create Critical section/Lock for a specific user

Tags: c#, web, synchronization, locking, critical-section

I am developing an eCommerce website which will be accessed by multiple users. I have a method **UpdateUserAmount()** which must be synchronized for a **specific user** i.e. we should not access the method UpdateUserAmount() simultaneously for the same user.

I am thinking of using a new static lock object for each user.I will create this object when the user enters the critical section and delete  it when he leaves.

This seems inefficient to me as we are creating as many objects as there are simultaneous users. Is there an efficient method of achieving the same?

```
UpdateUserAmount(int amt) {
    user.amount+=amt // critical section
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking of using a new [...] lock object for each user.

That's exactly what you'll need to do.